# Aggregate Report for Gradle Multi-Project build

Tags: gradle, aggregate, code-coverage, jacoco

I need to create an aggregate code coverage report for my multiple-module Gradle project using the JaCoCo plugin for Gradle, similar to the one generated by the `jacoco:aggregate-report` of Maven's `jaoco-maven-plugin`.

I have been googling for a solution the last couple of days but nothing has worked so far. Most of the proposed solutions involve defining a task of type JacocoReport in the root project, that aggregates the execution data and produces the html code coverage report. However everything I tried so far either fails with an error or does not generate any report.

For example, this code snippet that I have tried:

```
def publishedProjects = subprojects.findAll()

task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport) {

    dependsOn(publishedProjects.test)

    additionalSourceDirs = files(publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.output)
    executionData = files(publishedProjects.jacocoTestReport.executionData)

    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll { it.exists() })
    }

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = false
    }
}
```

gives the error `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'additionalSourceDirs' for task ':jacocoRootReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport`

The version of Gradle that I am using is 7.3. Unfortunately I'm very new to Gradle and I still cannot fiddle with the code snippets that I've found to make them work for my case.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is an official example in the Gradle docs for this use case:

https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage.html

It is a somewhat complex and requires an additional project that will serve as the aggregate. The way you have above is generally discouraged by Gradle for reasons outside of this question/answer.

---

**Edit 2022-09-11**

As of Gradle 7.4, Gradle now offers a plugin to aggregate reports for multi-module projects.

See the documentation for the [JaCoCo Report Aggregation Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html) for more details.

Comment: The aggregation plugin only aggregates reports of a particular _test type_, e.g. "unit-test" or "integration-test". The plugin can unfortunately not be used to "aggregate the aggregates", which is like super sad lol. One would have thought that an aggregation plugin would finally give me one single aggregated view over all the code coverage for the entire multi-project, but no 